# Show only a single sticky note?

Tags: notes, stickynotes

I'm using the built in gnome Sticky Notes app, which matches my needs perfectly*.  But I can't figure out how to show only 1 single note without showing *all* the notes.

There's nothing obvious in preferences/settings; are there any tricks or hacks that will allow me to show only a single note?  I'd also be OK with showing all the notes, then hiding them individually.

*Please no suggestions for Tomboy or other programs - they're all way too heavy for my needs. I don't need linking or formatting or search. I just need plain old tiny notes with the ability to show only one at a time.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up doing something supremely lame - but it works!  I unchecked "Put notes on all workspaces" in the preferences, then dragged each note so that it hung over the edge to another workspace.  Change over to the next workspace, and keep dragging the note until it's all on this space.  Shampoo, rinse, repeat - I left the 1 note I care about on workspace #1 and moved the rest to #2.

[The dragging is because w/o a proper menu bar, I didn't see a way to right-click and "move to workspace right" for the notes.]